# SQL Queries for division

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access, select

I am working on `Excel VBA` where I am writing `SQL` code to fetch date from Access database. I am concerned about a division query.

I am writing a `SQL query` in **vba** to get the aggregated sum from a particular column and then divide it by a particular numeric value.

**e.g.**

```
SELECT SUM("column1") FROM table_name;
```

I want the **`Sum("column1")`** to divide by a numeric value i.e. by 1M.

Answer (score 1):

You can use arithmetic operations and numeric literals in queries:

```sql
SELECT SUM(mycolumn) / 1000000 FROM mytable
```